# Merge and resize png images

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to merge two .png images and resize the output, I have this code:

```
public function image($bg = null, $img = null)
{
        define("WIDTH", 1200);
        define("HEIGHT", 1200);

        $dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        imagesavealpha($dest_image, true);

        $trans_background = imagecolorallocatealpha($dest_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);

        imagefill($dest_image, 0, 0, $trans_background);

        $a = imagecreatefrompng('./test/'.$bg);
        $b = imagecreatefrompng('./test/'.$img);

        imagecopy($dest_image, $a, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        imagecopy($dest_image, $b, 0, 0, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($dest_image);

        imagedestroy($a);
        imagedestroy($b);
        imagedestroy($dest_image);
}
```

this code return png image in original size, how to make this function returns the image in another size like (200*200px)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html#two-types-of-watermarking

Or use ImageMagik, good extention. But need to bi instaled on a server.